Asset Libraries (File Paths) has an error

Hello, for some reason, the File Path is automatically added, and duplicated to >100+ paths. The name suggests that the Fluid Painter folder has the error. Do you know how to fix it ??

We can only help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons on this Q&A site. Fluid Painter is a third-party addon so you'll have to contact the addon author for help

Oh, I think this is the Blender Path error. Thanks, I will contact the addon author for help
